# How do SpriteKit positions work?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, positioning, cgpoint

I'm building a game and I've noticed that when I do something like

```
node.position = CGPointMake(0, 0) //Bottom Left
node.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0) //Bottom Left
```

that depending on which phone you have iPhone 4s, 5s, 6s ect. It shows up in different places.

How can I change it so that it uses the bounds of the screen size to work out its calculation like

```
self.view.frame.width/2
```

Cheers, I'm guessing its scale issue?

Comment: Which scale mode are you using?

Comment: Aspect Fill, I think i may have fixed it, i have to set it too the bounds of the screen x2, i dunno why x2 i guess because retina screens render at 2x?

Comment: If you want use Aspect Fill, your playable area must be the ratio of iPad/iPhone4. If you want use all playable area, use Aspect Fit. This because if you are working around multi device, the use of self.view.frame will be complicated to manage every node position.

Answer (score 0):

Use bounds

```
self.view.bounds.size
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in GameScene.sks. On the right side of the editor, you can see the dimensions of the screen. The point value is the scene's coordinate positions. To make it standard across devices, in App Delegate, under applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, `scene.scalemode = .AspectFill`. The scalemode has many different options to stretch the .sks file's dimensions to the device's screen. You can read about them here: [understanding scalemodes](http://blog.infinitecortex.com/2014/01/spritekit-understanding-skscene-scalemode/). The scalemodes are called like so: .ResizeFill . ResizeFit etc..